SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get transaction: invalid signature
How do I resolve this error from the solana web3 library?
const receipt = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.getTransaction(txHash, { commitment: 'finalized', maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 })


Can you see the transaction in explorer.solana.com ?
